# Tensorflow2 - How to assing name to a tf_op_layer?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

One of my model outcomes is a `tf_op_layer`, I'd need to assign an outcome name for it. However, I noticed that the argument name is not working for `tf_op_layer` in general.

A dummy example of what I'm facing. At the summary, it can be seen the missing name for the op_layer. On the other hand, it works well for Dense Layer.

```
x_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='input_test')
x = tf.keras.layers.Subtract(name='subtraction_1')([x_input, tf.constant([[12.]])])
x_out_1 = tf.keras.layers.Multiply(name='multiply_1')([x, tf.constant([[3.]])])
x_out_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='dense_1')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(x_input, [x_out_1, x_out_2])
model.summary()

# Model: "model"
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
# ==================================================================================================
# input_test (InputLayer)         [(None, 1)]          0                                            
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# tf_op_layer_sub (TensorFlowOpLa [(None, 1)]          0           input_test[0][0]                 
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# tf_op_layer_mul (TensorFlowOpLa [(None, 1)]          0           tf_op_layer_sub[0][0]            
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            2           tf_op_layer_sub[0][0]            
# ==================================================================================================
# Total params: 2
# Trainable params: 2
# Non-trainable params: 0
# _________________________
```

I'm using TensorFlow version 2.1.0.

Are there other ways that I can properly assign a name for the op_layer?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can reproduce on tf 2.3 but not on 2.4. The easiest is probably to upgrade to tf 2.4